# How to automatically extract content from an Excel cell and paste a specific part of it into new cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, price

In EXCEL, I'm trying to extract from this cell:

```
'<p> 4 text r<br /> $7000 - 8000</p>
```

To turn it automatically into this in a new cell:

```
$7000 to $8000
```

This is the latest formula I have tried:

> =MID(BC395,SEARCH(">",BC395)+1,SEARCH("0",BC395)-SEARCH(">",BC395)-2)

BC395 is the cell where I'm extracting from.

Any ideas on how to avoid the other irrelevant text info and numbers in the first cell? I need it to move clean into the new cell with the "dollar" sign and the word "to" in between the range.

Comment: To get answers, you are expected to post your current coding effort within your question. Please edit your question and do that.

Comment: Take a look at formulas LEFT, RIGHT, LEN and MID and combine them to get in a new Column only the values you want. Also, the Replace function in Excel can help you to get rid of characters you don't want. For example, Replace "-" with "to"

Comment: No, don't post that in the comments. Instead, edit your question add it there as `code`.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns thank you! Have been trying with MID but failed so far. Will try to combine as you said.

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the string will always include

```
$n - n<
```

where `n` is any number, but the relevant string is preceded by a `$` and followed by a `<`

Then you can try this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("$",A1)-1,""),FIND("<",REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("$",A1)-1,""))-1),"- ","to $")
```

Change `A1` to `BC395` or wherever you have your string.

If there is variability in the string, I would suggest a VBA User Defined Function, looking for the `7000 - 8000` portion.